# System.Net.WebException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, httpwebrequest

```
var uploadImagesURL = "https://localhost:57028/Photo/UploadImages?albumId="+ albumId;
cookieString = parsedFormBody.Result.GetParameterValue("Cookie");

HttpWebRequest uploadImageWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadImagesURL);
uploadImageWebRequest.Method = "POST";
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
string[] cookiePairs = cookieString.Split(';');
foreach (string cookiePair in cookiePairs)
{
    string[] keyValue = cookiePair.Trim().Split('=');
    if (keyValue.Length == 2)
    {
        string cookieName = keyValue[0];
        string cookieValue = keyValue[1];
        var cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue)
        {
            Domain = "localhost"
        };
        cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
uploadImageWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;                                  
HttpWebResponse uploadImageWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)uploadImageWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

I have created an Azure function for the scalability purpose for uploading multiple images and from ajax request I'm calling my azure function and from azure function i'm uploading to wasabi and when the images are uploaded successfully then I'm making a call to the HttpWebRequest but on the step (HttpWebResponse)uploadImageWebRequest.GetResponse(); it is resulting into an error - System.Net.WebException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Comment: Why don't you use `HttpClient` given that `WebRequest` is deprecated? Also `+ memoryStream` is weird, you can't concat a memory stream like that. Instead you need to get the bytes and convert to base64 or similar first.

Answer (score 0):

> error - System.Net.WebException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

- Mostly, these issues encounter with SSL certificates or security restrictions. If you're running the application locally, try using `http://localhost:57028` instead of `https://localhost:57028`

I had tried a sample web API where HttpWebRequest will post the name and values to the cookies. please check the below code.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    class WebApplication2
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
                string postData = "{\"title\":\"New Post\",\"body\":\"This is the post body\",\"userId\":1}";

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";

                // Convert the POST data to a byte array
                byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;

                // Add cookies to the request
                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("session_id", "abc123", "/", "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"));
                request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("auth_token", "xyz789", "/", "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"));

                // Write the POST data to the request stream
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
                }

                // Send the request and get the response
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    // Read the response stream using a StreamReader
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseText);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Response is HttpWebResponse response)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HTTP error: " + response.StatusCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- I have added the try-catch method in the above code to handle the exceptions which occurs when web request is Sent.

**Results:**
[image]